# Trouble opening DB environment in Oracle Berkeley DB

Tags: c++, visual-c++, berkeley-db

I'm new to databases and I wrote this practice program to test Berkeley BDB. I'm getting trouble opening the environment - the error appears in my console and says:

```
testEnv\_db.001: No such file or directory
Error opening database environment
DbEnv::open: No such file or directory
```

The code of the console program is based strongly off the examples in the Berkeley DB Transactions guide, and here's the text of the program up to the error, under `int main()`.

```
String^ key_allkeys  = "_ALLKEYS";
String^ key_valcount = "_COUNT";

// 1. Print some information to the screen, prompt user to enter path for key-value pair location:
Console::WriteLine("Oracle Berkeley DB Example Database Creator");
Console::WriteLine();
Console::WriteLine("Enter the path to the text file of key-value pairs:");
String^ kv_path = Console::ReadLine();

// 2. Declare initial variables:
String^ totalkeys;
int totalval;

// 3. Open the database:
u_int32_t env_flags = DB_CREATE | DB_INIT_LOCK | DB_INIT_LOG | DB_INIT_MPOOL | DB_INIT_TXN; 
std::string envHome("testEnv");
u_int32_t db_flags = DB_CREATE | DB_AUTO_COMMIT;
Db *dbp = NULL;
const char *file_name = "mydb.db";
DbEnv myEnv(0);
try 
{
    myEnv.open(envHome.c_str(), env_flags, 0);
    dbp = new Db(&myEnv, 0);
    dbp->open(NULL, file_name, NULL, DB_BTREE, db_flags, 0); 
} 
catch(DbException &e) 
{
    std::cerr << "Error opening database environment: " << std::endl;
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    exc_block(); // Block
    return (EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

It should be fairly obvious that the program is failing right around the `try`/`catch` blocks. I've read the manual (literally RTFM) and I couldn't figure it out - the `DB_CREATE` flag is specified for both the environment and database, so there shouldn't be an issue here.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It may simply be that the testEnv directory doesn't exist in the directory where you are running the program?  You have to create the environment home directory yourself.

Also, you may wish to specify DB_RECOVER when opening the environment.